# How to describe in OpenAPI that the same response may either contain a response body, or the response body may be completely absent

Tags: httpresponse, openapi

Our API returns various response codes. For some response codes 4xx and above, a body may be returned. For example, an HTTP response code of 400 may be returned in several different cases described in the business logic, in some cases the response may contain a body, and in some cases the body may be completely absent.

My question is - how can I describe in the specification a situation where, for the same HTTP response code, for example, for HTTP 400, the API can return a response body or there can be no response body at all?

Addition. I am trying to describe the HTTP response code for the same endpoint.

Examples:

The response contains a body:

```
    '400':
      description: Bad Request
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: some_ref_here
          examples:
            example-1:
              value:
                message:
                  title: This email address cannot be used
                  detail: Use a different email address.
                  severity: error
      headers:
        Content-Type:
          schema:
            type: string
          description: Some description.
        Cache-Control:
          schema:
            type: string
          description: Some description.
        Pragma:
          schema:
            type: string
          description: Some description.
```

The response does not contain a body:

```
    '400':
      description: Bad Request
      headers:
        Content-Type:
          schema:
            type: string
          description: Some description.
        Cache-Control:
          schema:
            type: string
          description: Some description.
        Pragma:
          schema:
            type: string
          description: Some description.
```

I'm trying to specify for a 400 HTTP code that it can either contain `content`, or `content` can be completely absent.

Answer (score 0):

That's the default. If the responses 'content' field is absent, it won't be validated against the provided response.

On the other hand, if you want to indicate that a response body must be present, you can do that indirectly by checking for a non-empty Content-Length or Content-Type header.

Comment: So how exactly can I specify that for a particular HTTP response code, the response body may be present OR may not be present at all using the OpenAPI specification?

Comment: I don't know if you can.  But this is all not very clear in the specification, and the implementation you are using may have chosen to interpret it differently, so you should check the documentation for your implementation to see if it offers any guidance.

Comment: @fallincode I'd suggest asking this in the OpenAPI Specification repository https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/discussions